# Get data from SQL Database in PHP for a table

Tags: php, sql

**EDIT** : Using `mysql_connect` in `PHP 7`. **Solved**.

I've try to make a table with the last entry in my Database, so i've try to get my last 5 data and repeat it in a table.

This is the structure of my Database:

```
CREATE TABLE `submitph` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phrase` text NOT NULL,
  `mode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `enable` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And my php code

```
<tbody>
                        <?php
                        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
                        mysql_select_db("jnj");
                            $retour = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM submitph ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5');
                            while ($donnees = mysql_fetch_array($retour))
                            {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <?php echo stripslashes($donnees['id']); ?>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <?php 
                                 $phrase = nl2br(stripslashes($donnees['phrase']));
                                 echo $phrase;
                            ?>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <a href="">Approuver</a> / <a href="">Refuser</a>
                          </td>

                        </tr>
                        <?php
}    ?>

                      </tbody>
```

But i didn't have any data in my table, i didn't have any php error,  didn't understand why. Did i miss something ?

EDIT 1 (All my table) :

```
       <table class="table table-hover">
                      <thead class="">
                                <th>
                          ID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          Phrase
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          Status
                        </th>

                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                                            <?php
                        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
                        mysql_select_db("jnj");
                            $retour = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM submitph ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5');
                            while ($donnees = mysql_fetch_array($retour))
                            {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <?php echo stripslashes($donnees['id']); ?>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <?php 
                                 $phrase = nl2br(stripslashes($donnees['phrase']));
                                 echo $phrase;
                            ?>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <a href="">Approuver</a> / <a href="">Refuser</a>
                          </td>

                        </tr>
                        <?php
} 
?>

                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

EDIT 2 : SQL Data

```
INSERT INTO `submitph` (`id`, `phrase`, `mode`, `enable`) VALUES
(3, 'Test1', 'Hard', 0),
(5, 'Test2', 'Soft', 0),
(6, 'Test3', 'Hard', 0);
```

[image: SQL DATA]

Comment: Do you actually have any rows in your database table?

Comment: @user3647971: Yes, i edit my post, i've put all my HTML code. @ivion : I've try to remove `LIMIT` option like `SELECT * FROM submitph ORDER BY id` but that's not working too

Comment: `stripslashes` doesn't protect against XSS, you are thinking about [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: You are fetching array, maybe you want to fetch `associative array` with `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: The mysql extension of php is deprecated anyway @Dharman I think this is more of a learning process rather than bank security :)

Comment: @user3647971 Either way, I wanted to clear it up so that OP is aware of it.

Comment: @Argardor You sure there are no php errors? Since you are fetching array and accessing it with associative keys that should generate errors. As I said in previous comment above, you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` by default returns an array with both numeric and string indices - so this is not a problem. The OP should check that `mysql_num_rows($retour)` is greater than zero and also make a `var_dump($donnees)` to see how each row looks like

Comment: No i didn't have any php Error, i use MAMP, i've edited php.ini for enable `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL`, but no error. `mysql_fetch_assoc` didn't working too

Comment: You are not clear. Are you having any values populated in your table?

Comment: @Argardor Does the `html` table have any empty rows in the table? Also if not then the query is not being executed provided that you have the corresponding rows and table in your database. Or it is executed, but it fails for some unknown reason that is not clear from the data you have provided

Comment: @hotheadhacker: i've edit and put a picture of my database. I think that's great for you :). @user3647971 : I've try to remove `<?php echo ....; ?>` and put a fake data in HTML Code, that's work great.

Comment: @Argardor I meant that when you echoed the table rows... did any __empty__ rows show up in your html table?

Comment: Oh god, i think i've find the error. I'll use `mysql_connect` function in PHP7. I'll try to do it in PDO.

Comment: @Argardor Yeah, mysql extension is deprecated in php7, pdo is much safer and more convenient. You should look up __prepared statements__

Comment: It's ok, i'll try to read somes manuals for understand PDO & try to make a code. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing $connection variable to mysql_query();

Comment: This is optional for `mysql_query()`

Comment: Try to store mysql_connect to a $conn variable and make your sql_connect query as: mysql_connect('some sql query', $conn) ;

Comment: Not sorry, the problem is i using `mysql_connect` in `PHP7`

Comment: Ah mysqli_connect